# Android: синхронизация настоящего времени

Tags: android, дата, время, datetime

Телефон долгое время пролежал без аккумулятора. После того, как я вставил аккумулятор я включаю телефон. В нём установлено моё приложение с `Activity`, запускающейся сразу при включении телефона. Она запрашивает данную дату и время

```
String mDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss", mLocale).format(new Date());
```

где

```
mLocale = new Locale("ru", "RU");
```

или

```
mLocale = Locale.getDefault();
```

то есть пробовал и так и так. Строка `mDate` отображается в сообщении:

```
Toast.makeText(this, mDate, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**Но дата не верна!** Отображается 1 января 2012 года и 4:00 утра. Есть ли какой-то способ вызвать системную команду синхронизации даты и времени перед тем, как их запрашивать? То есть как-то так:

```
synchronizeTime(); // дождаться синхронизации времени
String mDate = ...; // получить настоящее корректное время
Toast.makeText(this, mDate, ...).show(); // показать время
```

Или, хотя бы, создать какой-нибудь нормальный `BroadcastReceiver` с событием чего-то типа `android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED`.

Comment: системмной нет. Вы можете синхронизировать время через интернет с какким-либо сервером прежде, чем запрашивать ее.